Set filetype based on custom file extension in neovim
I have created filetype config in below format
.config/nvim
├── after
│   └── ftplugin
│       └── gitconfig-gh.lua

And the content is:
vim.opt.filetype = 'gitconfig'

But still the syntax highlighting with treesitter is not working. It only works when I open the file and set it each time
nvim ~/.gitconfig-gh
:set filetype=gitconfig

Am I missing something here? Is there any other way to set filetype based on extension?

For the next person looking for customizing filetypes
Adding a filetype pattern in init.lua solves the problem
vim.filetype.add({
  pattern = {
    ['.*/.gitconfig-*'] = 'gitconfig',
  },
})


More info on vim.filetype.add()

Your ftplugin/gitconfig-gh.lua file is only used if your opened file is detected with filetype == gitconfig-gh (see :help ftplugin).
But by default, Neovim doesn't recognize this filetype for your ~/.gitconfig-gh file => see nvim/runtime/lua/vim/filetype.lua file installed with Neovim.
$ grep gitconfig /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/filetype.lua
  ['.gitconfig'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.gitmodules'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*/etc/gitconfig%.d/.*'] = starsetf('gitconfig'),
  ['.*/%.gitconfig%.d/.*'] = starsetf('gitconfig'),
  ['.*%.git/modules/.*/config'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*%.git/modules/config'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*%.git/config'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*/etc/gitconfig'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*/%.config/git/config'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*%.git/config%.worktree'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['.*%.git/worktrees/.*/config%.worktree'] = 'gitconfig',
  ['${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/git/config'] = 'gitconfig',

If you want to set filetype = gitconfig for your file based on pattern, you could create an Lua autocommand in your nvim configuration.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('BufRead', {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('detect_gitconfig', { clear = true }),
  desc = 'Set filetype for gitconfig-* files',
  pattern = { '.gitconfig-*' },
  callback = function()
    vim.cmd('set filetype=gitconfig')
  end,
})


This too solves the problem. Found that vim.filetype.add() can also be used.
